# React-Native - How to replace functionality of a react-native core component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have already created a web app and I need to convert it into a react-native-ios app. 
I have created a TextInput widget for the web app which does more than what the react-native TextInput componemt.

1. How could I overwrite core functionality of TextInput such as the onchange method.
2. How could I add extra functionality to the TextInput.

The web app's TextInput widget is written in JavaScript. I want to avoid objective-C, if at all possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand how you would overwrite onChange, since it is merely a callback function which doesn't do anything. What is it you like to change or do?

Comment: changing the onChange is just one of many scenarios. I need to know can I overwrite or change the functionality of the parameters that TextInput takes. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't (and probably can't) overwrite core functionality. Wouldn't a simple component decorator work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there is nothing react-native specific you would need to do here. You just use standard react techniques for adding functionality to existing components. So you can create a component which wraps TextInput, which allows you to pass thought any prop TextInput accepts. And you can just as well provide additional props to your component for other requirements.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { 
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';

class CustomInput extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {text: 'default text'}
  }

  render(): JSX.Element {

    return (
      <TextInput
        {...this.props} // pass through props
        value={this.state.text}
        onChangeText={this.onChangeText} // update value as usual
        onChange={this.props.doSomethingSpecial} // call custom prop function for custom behaviour
      />
    ); 
  }

  onChangeText = (text) => {
    this.setState({text});
  }
}

export default CustomInput;
```